# What am I missing? Trying to add a class name to html that I get back from server

Tags: jquery

I have an ajax request that gets back some html

```
<div id="test">
</div>
```

in my success method I have this

```
  $('#test', response).addClass('mytest');
 $('#SomethingOnMyPage').after(response);
```

Yet when I look at it on the page I don't see mytest. It is like it did not add the class.

I also tried

```
$(response).filter('div.test').addClass('mytest');
```

same result

Comment: `$(response).filter('div#test').addClass('mytest').appendTo("#SomethingOnMyPage");`

Comment: @3nigma `.appendTo()` is semantically different from `.after()`.

Comment: @MДΓΓБДLL yup thats y i didnt make it an answer...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `div#test` is really the outermost HTML element in the response, this is what you need:

```
var $elt = $(response).addClass('mytest');
$('#somethingOnYourPage').after($elt);
```

This is because `$('#test', response)` — which is equivalent to `$(response).find('#test')` — searches for descendants of the outermost element of `response`; since `#test` is the outermost element and not a descendant element, that selector won't match anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(response).filter('div.test').addClass('mytest');
```

This will not have worked because it would be looking for a div with a class 'test', not an ID 'test'.  You could try this one:

```
$(response).filter('#test').addClass('mytest');
```

To see if it works any differently.

Regarding the first part.  As stated by another answerer, `response` IS the div#test, so looking for #test **as a child** will always fail.  If this still isn't the solution, Try adding the fragment to the DOM *before* attempting to modify it (this shouldn't be required, but in doing this, you may discover exactly what is wrong with the fragment that your jQuery isn't working.)

Also, are you looking at this via "View Source" or through the developer tools of your browser?  If the prior, it will never show up, as it will only display the original HTML downloaded from the server before any JS is executed.